# Why still @Transectional with @Async method get timeout error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, server

Why I am still getting timeout error? Can anybody please help to figure out

> Application Entry point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync

public class MyWebapiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyWebapiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

> API Resource

```
public interface CatalogResource {
@DELETE
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{id}/items")
    public Response deleteCatalogItem(@PathParam("id") String catalogId,@QueryParam("community") String communityId,CatalogItemFilter catalogItemFilter);
}
```

> API Component Class:

```
@Component
public class CatalogComponent implements CatalogResource {
@Override
    public Response deleteCatalogItem( String catalogId, String communityId, CatalogItemFilter catalogItemFilter ){
        catalogService.deleteCatalogItem( catalogId, catalogItemFilter.getItemIdList(), communityId, userId );

        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
}
```

> Service class

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CatalogService {
    @Async
    @Transactional(readOnly=false, timeout = 1000)
    public void deleteCatalogItem( String catalogId, List<String> itemIdList, String communityId, String userId ){

> // Here time consuming multiple queries and getting exception

    }
}
```

I am getting timeout exception during `CatalogService.deleteCatalogItem` execution time. Can anybody help how to solve it.

The log for the exception is:

> Error querying database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   ERROR: canceling statement due to user request

Comment: Never tried this but, If you put @Transaction on any method, spring adds around advice on method and creates a proxy for the method.
 Inside proxy it adds begin transaction/commit transaction around your method in the proxy. Now since your actual method is running asynchronously and simultaneously,  I assume handle is not reaching to commit transaction part.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Spring Boot but assuming it works like JavaEE then the method will run asynchronously but will also be wrapped in an transaction by means of some interceptor/aroundinvoke aspect. That means the transaction handling will be part of the asynchronous call as well and if that call takes too long you'll still get a timeout. To solve this you'd either have to increase the timeout, improve performance of your code/queries or split the process into smaller and more manageable parts.

Comment: @Transactional(readOnly=false, timeout = 1000), the timeout settings are enough for my case. Any other suggestions.

Comment: Adding an `@Async` will not reduce the time it takes to execute your complex delete queries. Either fix/speedup your queries (see where you can improve them) else increase the timeout.

Comment: timeout = 1000, is sufficient, it's getting error after around 20 seconds.